# Strip tags and replace all br and p tags with a single space

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace

What is the regex to strip all html tags and where there are `<br>` and  `<p>` tags replace with a single space and remove all line breaks?

e.g:

```
<h1>Heading</h1>
<br>
<br />
<a href="#">hyperlink</a>
<p></p>
<p>paragraph1</p>
<p>paragraph2</p>
```

Should become:

```
Heading hyperlink paragraph1 paragraph2
```

I have tried the following:

```
$string = preg_replace( ["/<br\s*\/?>/i","/<\/p\s*>/i"]," ",$string);
$string = preg_replace(["/<\/?[^>]+>/", "/\r?\n|\r/"],"",$string);
```

Which gives me:

```
Heading              hyperlink         paragraph1 paragraph2
```

any ideas of a single line or more elegant solution which actually works?

Comment: @Nahiyan i want to remove ALL html. the above was just an example.

Comment: Did you try something like this: "preg_replace("/<h1>|<p>|</p>|</h1>/g", " ", $string)"?

Comment: What about this? preg_replace("/<[^>]*[/]*>/g", " ", $string);

Comment: Regex is not a good way to deal with this. You should use [DomDocument](http://php.net/manual/en/class.domdocument.php) to iterate through tags and get their innerHTML values and add space etc.

Comment: @vivek_23 what you are suggesting is overkill. All I want to do is strip all html and output a single line string. Where there are `br` and `p` tags i need to replace with a single space and if there are any line breaks they need to be removed

Comment: @adam78 it's not an overkill. It's the solution. Regex is not going to give you correct answers unless you have total control over what kind of HTML you are going to have.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is what I would do:

```
$a = '<h1>Heading</h1>
<br>
<br />
<a href="#">hyperlink</a>
<p></p>
<p>paragraph1</p>
<p>paragraph2</p>';


echo trim(preg_replace(['/<[^>]*>/','/\s+/'],' ', $a));
```

Output

```
 Heading hyperlink paragraph1 paragraph2
```

[Sandbox](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/1d83b91d27aad1026d85d15ef5323bb9fc120057)

The first regex removes tags replacing them with a space, the second one takes multiple spaces and changes it to one.

This works pretty good, but I can see a way that it could deviate from what was specifically requested.

> What is the regex to strip all html tags and where there are <br> and <p> tags replace with a single space and remove all line breaks

So if you want the "full" solution, you can do this:

```
$a = '<h1>Heading</h1>
<br>
<br />
<a href="#">hyperlink</a>
<p></p>
<p><big>p</big>aragraph1</p><p>paragraph2</p>';

echo preg_replace([
    '/<(?:br|p)[^>]*>/i', //replace br p with ' '
    '/<[^>]*>/',  //replace any tag with ''
    '/\s+/', //remove run on space
    '/^\s+|\s+$/' //trim
],[
    ' ', '', ' ', ''
], $a);
```

Please note i added a `<big>` tag in and removed any space between the `<p>` tags.  These were done to highlight a few things.

For example if you take the text from the second example and use it in the first you will get this (because the big tag):

```
Heading hyperlink p aragraph1 paragraph2
```

The updated example outputs correctly.  But, and this is a big but, I changed the input text, so it may not be necessary to over-complicate it.

The `<p>` tag thing just shows that it puts space in between them before removing all the HTML tags with ''.

[Sandbox](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/54d0dc145fc226687de883bd4f58a19b118a1fa5)

**UPDATE**

> @ArtisticPhoenix how would I accomodate `<p>&nbsp;</p>`

First I would convert the string using `html_entity_decode` however there are a few sticky points with that.  These have to do with encoding.  So this is the correct way to do it:

```
$a = '<h1>Heading</h1>
<br>
<br />
<a href="#">hyperlink</a>
<p>&nbsp;</p>
<p><big>p</big>aragraph1</p><p>paragraph2</p>';

 //convert entities using UTF-8
$a = html_entity_decode($a, ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8');

echo preg_replace([
    '/<(?:br|p)[^>]*>/i', //replace br p with ' '
    '/<[^>]*>/',  //replace any tag with ''
    '/\s+/u', //remove run on space - replace using the unicode flag
    '/^\s+|\s+$/u' //trim - replace using the unicode flag
],[
    ' ', '', ' ', ''
], $a);
```

Please note the addition of the `u` flag to the regex above `/\s+/u` and `/^\s+|\s+$/u`.

> **u (PCRE_UTF8)**
>   This modifier turns on additional functionality of PCRE that is incompatible with Perl. Pattern and subject strings are treated as UTF-8. An invalid subject will cause the preg_* function to match nothing; an invalid pattern will trigger an error of level E_WARNING. Five and six octet UTF-8 sequences are regarded as invalid since PHP 5.3.4 (resp. PCRE 7.3 2007-08-28); formerly those have been regarded as valid UTF-8.

The problem comes from decoding it into a `ASCII 160` (nbsp) instead of `ASCII 32` character (single space).  Anyway we can use UTF-8 to sort it out as shown above.

[Sandbox](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/acdf4d999ef23bfdecbe747453bab4599ef92e7c)

Comment: @ArtisticPhoenix: You wrote my regex wrongly. You are missing `+` in the regex I wrote. In your sandbox demo you are using `(\s*<[^>]+>\s*)` instead of my regex which is `(\s*<[^>]+>\s*)+` I think my regex is simple enough and works in one shot.

Comment: No kidding...  hadn't noticed.

Comment: @ArtisticPhoenix: It's okay dear. But my regex works and is simple enough.

Comment: @ArtisticPhoenix: Yours is correct too but isn't mine simpler?

Comment: @PushpeshKumarRajwanshi - no.  Your's is just an incomplete regex missing the delimiters.  Mine is actual runable code that a novice programmer can plug right into something and start getting experience with it.  Your's they have to figure out a few things.  If you really want to compare, we can.  But frankly I don't really care.

Comment: @ArtisticPhoenix: OP already knows how to do it in PHP codes, but nonetheless. I have added sample php codes in my answer too.

Comment: @ArtisticPhoenix how would I accomodate `<p>&nbsp;</p>`?

Comment: I would first use `html_entity_decode` on the string.  That is the best way, if you are just converting it to text, because it will also fix things like `&amp;` ampersand, and `&copy;` or any other html entities.  Because of the `/\s+/` run-on space replacement, any extra space added by converting the non-breaking space will just get swept up too.

Answer (score 4):

Treating HTML like a string and using regular expressions is never a good idea. The only decent solution that doesn't involve a DOM parser would be using PHP's built-in [`strip_tags`](https://php.net/strip-tags) function (which [uses](https://github.com/php/php-src/blob/master/ext/standard/string.c#L5012) a [state machine](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Finite-state_machine), so is still vulnerable to potential problems with broken HTML) and then you can compact the resulting whitespace with a regex:

```
<?php
$html = '<h1>Heading</h1>
<br>
<br />
<a href="#">hyperlink</a>
<p></p>
<p>paragraph1</p>
<p>paragraph2</p>';

echo preg_replace("/\s+/", " ", strip_tags($html));
```

Output:

```
Heading hyperlink paragraph1 paragraph2
```

Answer (score 0):

You can group multiple tags that are surrounded by white spaces and replace them with a single space. The regex to be replaced would be,

```
(\s*<[^>]+>\s*)+
```

This would give you a single space in place of all those tags and finally use `trim()` to get rid of right most and left space spaces that you may not need.

**[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/XsR5RH/1)**

Here is the php code for demo,

```
$html = '<h1>Heading</h1>
<br>
<br />
<a href="#">hyperlink</a>
<p></p>
<p>paragraph1</p>
<p>paragraph2</p>';

echo trim(preg_replace("/(\s*<[^>]+>\s*)+/", " ", $html));
```

Prints,

```
Heading hyperlink paragraph1 paragraph2
```

Comment: What if innerHTML has `<` and `>` ?

Comment: Like OP wants, even those inner tag will be removed. Although in general html shouldn't be manipulated with regex, but I suggested this as the OP's case can be dealt with it. Check here, where even inner tags will be replaced with space retaining any text within the tags if any. [Demo](https://regex101.com/r/XsR5RH/2)

Comment: I mean with content like `x < y and a > b` .

Comment: @vivek_23: Have you ever seen a real html data like that? Unless you artificially make one :) Although I can make my regex tighter if OP has such kind of data to handle. Instead of `<[^>]+>` it would just become `<\w[^>]*>`

Comment: And if you have malformed tags like `<   sometag   some attributes etc etc>` the regex can changed to `<\s*\w[^>]*>` to handle extra space before the tag name. Such kind of small modifications can always be done easily, depending upon the data. But unless you know what kind of data is going to be there, it is not really worth to make your regex complicated.

Comment: Well, it doesn't trim. So it leaves a leading and trailing space.... but whatever.

Comment: @ArtisticPhoenix: I already wrote in my post, you can simply do `trim($str)` to trim it.

Comment: @PushpeshKumarRajwanshi I agree and there could be HTML data like that. Take any mathematical site for example. It might have these symbols written in it's DOM to explain some mathematical concepts etc. Moreover, like you said before, regex is never a solution to such things and I am sure OP will misguide many future post referrers to use regex for such things.

Comment: @vivek_23: I agree with you HTML should never be parsed using regex. But one of the main reason of it, is HTML can contain nested structures which regex can't handle. But in OP's case, there is neither nested tags, nor it would have even impacted, if it actually had nested tags. Because all OP want's is to get rid of tags. So for this particular task, OP can surely write one line of code to achieve his task. So wisdom is not always blindly following a rule, rather knowing when to use and when not to use. But yes, in general regex shouldn't be used for HTML.

Answer (score 0):

**You can use this**

```
<\s*\/?\s*br[^>]*>|<\s*\/?\s*p[^>]*>|\n
```

> Explanation

- `<\s*\/?\s*br[^>]*>` - Matches `<br>` or `</br>` or `<br/>` with any number of white space and matches attributes also.
- `<\s*\/?\s*p[^>]*>` - Matches `<p>` or `</p>` or `<p/>` with any number of white space matches attributes also.
- `\n` - Matches new line.

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/5DtyVI/5/)

Comment: `p` tag can have attributes.

Comment: @Code it doesn't replace Uppercase `<Br>` nor does it replace the line breaks and all other html tags

Comment: @adam78 you can turn on case insensitive flag for that. and for `\n` i have updated answer

Answer (score 0):

You could keep what you have an remove extra spaces

```
$stripped = preg_replace('/\s+/', ' ', $string);
```

That returns:

```
Heading hyperlink paragraph1 paragraph2
```

Comment: still end up with and extra space between `hyperlink` and `paragraph1`

Answer (score 0):

The way to do it is by using two patterns

**P1** : `<[\/\d\w]+.*?>`
which will clean all the tags.

**P2** : `[\n\s]+` and replace it by **single Whitespace**

Exemple :

```
$string = preg_replace( "<[\/\d\w]+.*?>","",$string);
$string = preg_replace("[\n\s]+"," ",$string);
```